# Increasing number of permutations of all possible combinations of a list with repetitions allowed

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying without success to understand how to use itertools to generate a list with all possible combinations of the elements of a list, with an increasing size of elements to pick and including repetitions.
I would like to add also a separator:

```
lis = ['a','b','c']
separator = '/'
total_number_of_combinations = 3
permutation_list = ['a','b','c', 'a/a', 'a/b', 'a/c', 'b/a', 'b/b', 'b/c', 'c/a', 'c/b', 'c/c',
                    'a/a/a', 'a/a/b', 'a/a/c', 'a/b/a', 'a/b/b', 'a/b/c', 'a/c/a', 'a/c/b', 'a/c/c'
                    'b/a/a', 'b/a/b', 'b/a/c', 'b/b/a', 'b/b/b', 'b/b/c', 'b/c/a', 'b/c/b', 'b/c/c'
                    'c/a/a', 'c/a/b', 'c/a/c', 'c/b/a', 'c/b/b', 'c/b/c', 'c/c/a', 'c/c/b', 'c/c/c']
```

The list will have then `len(lis)+len(lis)**2+len(lis)**3+...++len(lis)**n` elements, with `n=total_number_of_combinations`.
I need to keep the separator and the total_numbers_of_combinations changeables.

I need this in a list that can be check as a condition for filtering a pandas DataFrame (i will check `dt[dt.my_col.isin(permutation_list)]`)

I appreciate any help or pointing to a duplicated topic or even an explanation of how to correctly state this problem, because I did not found any topic that answer this question (maybe I am using the wrong keywords...). Maybe also there is a function from another module that does that, but I don't know.

UPDATE:
Following the request of @Scott, here is my real case:

```
lis = ['BRUTELE','COCKPIT EST', 'CIRCET']
separator = ' / '
total_number_of_combinations = 10
```

so my final list need to have 88572 elements.

Comment: Can you give a concrete (if incomplete) example of the list you want to end up with, relative to the value of `n`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to get is a product, not a combination.

```py
lis = ["BRUTELE", "COCKPIT EST", "CIRCET"]
separator = " / "
total_number_of_combinations = 3

result = list(
    itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        (separator.join(a) for a in itertools.product(lis, repeat=i))
        for i in range(1, total_number_of_combinations + 1)
    )
)

assert result == ['BRUTELE', 'COCKPIT EST', 'CIRCET', 'BRUTELE / BRUTELE', 'BRUTELE / COCKPIT EST', 'BRUTELE / CIRCET', 'COCKPIT EST / BRUTELE', 'COCKPIT EST / COCKPIT EST', 'COCKPIT EST / CIRCET', 'CIRCET / BRUTELE', 'CIRCET / COCKPIT EST', 'CIRCET / CIRCET', 'BRUTELE / BRUTELE / BRUTELE', 'BRUTELE / BRUTELE / COCKPIT EST', 'BRUTELE / BRUTELE / CIRCET', 'BRUTELE / COCKPIT EST / BRUTELE', 'BRUTELE / COCKPIT EST / COCKPIT EST', 'BRUTELE / COCKPIT EST / CIRCET', 'BRUTELE / CIRCET / BRUTELE', 'BRUTELE / CIRCET / COCKPIT EST', 'BRUTELE / CIRCET / CIRCET', 'COCKPIT EST / BRUTELE / BRUTELE', 'COCKPIT EST / BRUTELE / COCKPIT EST', 'COCKPIT EST / BRUTELE / CIRCET', 'COCKPIT EST / COCKPIT EST / BRUTELE', 'COCKPIT EST / COCKPIT EST / COCKPIT EST', 'COCKPIT EST / COCKPIT EST / CIRCET', 'COCKPIT EST / CIRCET / BRUTELE', 'COCKPIT EST / CIRCET / COCKPIT EST', 'COCKPIT EST / CIRCET / CIRCET', 'CIRCET / BRUTELE / BRUTELE', 'CIRCET / BRUTELE / COCKPIT EST', 'CIRCET / BRUTELE / CIRCET', 'CIRCET / COCKPIT EST / BRUTELE', 'CIRCET / COCKPIT EST / COCKPIT EST', 'CIRCET / COCKPIT EST / CIRCET', 'CIRCET / CIRCET / BRUTELE', 'CIRCET / CIRCET / COCKPIT EST', 'CIRCET / CIRCET / CIRCET']
```

However, the number of resulting items is *O*(`len(lis) ** total_number_of_combinations`), which may be computationally expensive. A better method would be parsing a string by splitting at separators and testing the membership of each split string.

Comment: Thanks im0j, this does the trick. But pay attention that the total number of elements is not `len(lis)**total_number_of_combinations`. the list you give for example has 39 elements. Anyway, sorry for not knowing that it is a product, not a combination. Should the title or anything be changed?

Comment: I edited my answer using Big-O notation. And I think title is fine as is it now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
[ '/'.join([*a]) for i in range(1,3) for a in itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEF', i) ]
```

Result is:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 
'A/A', 'A/B', 'A/C', 'A/D', 'A/E', 'A/F', 'B/B', 'B/C', 'B/D', 'B/E', 'B/F', 'C/C', 'C/D', 'C/E', 'C/F', 'D/D', 'D/E', 'D/F', 'E/E', 'E/F', 'F/F']
```

The following will give you 39 entries:

```
['/'.join([*a]) for i in range(1,4) for a in itertools.product(['a','b','c'],repeat=i)]
```

Please notice, that your given reference only has 35 entries, since `{'a/c/c', 'b/a/a', 'b/c/c', 'c/a/a'}` are missing. I see no logic why these are missing, so I assume an error with your list.

Comment: Hello @Jacob, thanks for your answer. Not really this. If you substitute your 'ABCDEF' for a list of strings (like my variable lis), you will not get the right number of elements.

Comment: Hello @CayoEmilio I have found a solution that matches your requirement. Please mark as solution if helpful :)

Comment: Thanks Jacob, indeed a more elegant solution. Well, here I see the 39 entries....